# Parsley.js validate functions without dom elements

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I love using the parsely form validation helpers in instances where I have a form. But, I would love to be able to access the validation functions manually for instances where I just have a variable in some JS code that I'd like to validate. ie)

```
var someEmail = "hello@gmail.com";
parsely.isEmail(someEmail);
```

Now, I'm aware that this is a trivial example and there are tons of regex's available for me to create my own isEmail() function. But, if I'm already including parsely which has tons of built in validation functions it would be great to leverage them.

Does anyone know of a way to do this without having to create placeholder DOM elements on the fly like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884016/can-parsley-js-work-without-form-element) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no (easy) way to access validation directly, but it's very easy to validate a "virtual" input, no need to add anything to the DOM:

```
$('<input>').parsley({type: 'email'}).isValid(true, someEmail);
```